# Android File Loading from sd card

Tags: android, file-upload, android-sdcard, android-file

im trying to do a file upload using http post but when I try to use a file from the micro-sd card on my phone, it doesn't create it so that I can upload it. It works perfectly when selecting files from the main phone storage, just not the sd card.

Im using an external library for the file selection dialog, which returns this when I try to select an image from the sd card (in this example its a photo taken from the camera app):
`/sdcard-ext/dcim/Camera/2012-07-02_12-28-19_548.jpg`

This is returned from just a random image I found in the OS files on the phone:
`/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1331049921270.jpg` I know this one looks like its on an sd card too (or at least it does to me), but this is definitely the phone's storage.

Here is the code I am currently using for the file upload:
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myURL);

    MultipartEntity mp = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    String mimeType = getFileMimeType(filePath);//the filePath is passed to the function
    that this code is contained inside and is initially sent from the file selection dialog
    mp.addPart("fileupload", new FileBody(new File(filePath), mimeType));

    httppost.setEntity(mp);

    String response = EntityUtils.toString( httpclient.execute( httppost ).getEntity(), "UTF-8" );
    System.out.println(response);

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

If any of could explain why this works for the phone's internal storage and not the removable sd card, that would be great!
Thanks.

UPDATE: I'm targeting Android 2.2 if that makes any difference. If it doesn't make any difference, I'm still targeting Android 2.2

Comment: What permissions have you requested in your manifest?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`
Is there one specifically for the external SDCARD that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Note: You should also see a "permission denied" error in the logcat, which should have alerted you to this problem.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, to just read from the external storage you need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: are you sure this permission would prevent me from even just reading from the external storage? I don't ever write anything there so im still a bit confused about this solution.

Comment: Edited my answer. Didn't realize that you were just trying to read.

Comment: Excellent, that fixed the access issues. In the process I found that other files weren't being saved when uploaded from the normal storage, but it was merely a problem with the max file size on the server end. Thanks for the help with the SDCARD issue!